# Laravel 5.2 Model sync() except field

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, synchronization

So I'm having $user as an instance of User model, and when I'm doing 
`$user->data()->sync($new_data)` the fields **address, country and postal_code** get updated.

But what if I want to update **everything except country**? Is there some way to do like
`$user->data()->sync($new_data)->except('country')`?

Can't find anything in docs so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`updateExistingPivot`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) as:

```
$attributes = ['address' => 'some_value', 'postal_code' => 'some_value'];
$user->data()->updateExistingPivot($data_id, $attributes);
```